# how to match end of string or space in a java regex

Tags: java, regex, eol

I have gotten a java regex representing "end of string or space" to work using a capture group ($|\s).  However, this seems like a hack because I'm not trying to **capture** anything.  Shouldn't I be using a set of square brackets to indicate a set/character class?  Is there something better I should be using?

---

Extraneous details below:

My actual goal is to grab the http port from this string:

> 2019-11-14 23:58:12.321  INFO 55572 --- [           main]
>   s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s):
>   51447/http

This line in the log may also come in the form of:

> 2019-11-14 23:58:12.321  INFO 55572 --- [           main]
>   s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s):
>   51447/http 51448/https

So I need to match "http" exactly and not "https" and specify "http" followed by a whitespace (so it can't be https) or "http" followed by the end of the line.

So my java code is:

> (\\d+)/http($|\\s)

Comment: What's the problem with what you're using now ?

Comment: Well you don't need the /http either, but you aren't concerned about capturing it? Look into the "positive lookahead" concept. Or just access capture group 1 and disregard the full match string.

Comment: Make it a non capturing group `(?:$|\\s)` or use positive lookahead

Comment: Do you need the only regex solution?

Answer (score 3):

Try positive lookahead

```
(\d+)(?=\/http($|\s))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a word boundary:

```
\b(\d+)/http\b
```

This will prevent `https` matches but would also match at the very end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't prefer to use the capturing group, you can use positive lookahead, but just check for a word boundary at the end of the "http" term. Lookahead is used in regular expressions when you want to match a term that occurs before a second term, but you don't want to include the second term in your match. As such, consider trying:

```
\\d+(?=/http\\b)
```

Here, only the digits are matched. The `(?=` term is the positive lookahead term. Note that it won't capture "/http" and include it in your match. But, it will only match the digits if the digits are suffixed with "/http". The `\\b` term ensures that only "http" that exists as an independent word will be matched. Thus, "https" won't be matched, but "http" that has a space after it or a newline or just the end of input will be matched. Hopefully, that helps.

Comment: I like your explanation, but I find that word boundary `\b` is often overused in an imprecise manner. There are many things which qualify as word boundaries other than whitespace and begin/end of input.

Comment: @PatrickParker Fair point. That being said, with regexes there is often a balance between precision, succinctness, and simplicity. Here I thought that the `\b` metacharacter struck that balance. But I often don't use it for the reasons you mentioned (in most cases of natural language text, specifically). Given the fact that these server logs aren't as loose as freeform text, I thought that the use of `\b` would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to match specific words in a string

```
.*\\bhttp\\b.*
```

in java

```
String matcher="2019-11-14 23:58:12.321 INFO 55572 --- [ main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 51447/http 51448/https";
System.out.println(matcher.matches(".*\\bhttp\\b.*"));  //returns true


String matcher="2019-11-14 23:58:12.321 INFO 55572 --- [ main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 51447 51448/https";     // removed http to test
System.out.println(matcher.matches(".*\\bhttp\\b.*"));   // returns false
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is matching end of line (`$`) or space(`\\s`) also,
Use look ahead (`?=`) to check for space or end of line instead

```
(\\d+)\\/http(?=$|\\s)
```

This would match what you are looking for, you can use also

```
:\\s+(\\d+)
```